# My input contains NaN, infinity, or value too large for dtype -

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to run PCA on a dataset but I am running into an issue involving NaN. I tried dropping multiple columns and changing the datatypes of my dataframe, but none of these worked.

My piece of my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
features = ['caloroies','protein','fat','sodium','fiber','carbo','sugars','potass','vitamins','shelf','weight','cups']

x = df.loc[:, features].values
y = df.loc[:,['rating_bucketed']].values

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(Data = principalComponents
                       , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
```

The error I receive from this is as follows:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

If I check my x variable, I receive the following:

```
print(x)

    [[     nan 4.00e+00 1.00e+00 1.30e+02 1.00e+01 5.00e+00 6.00e+00 2.80e+02
  2.50e+01 3.00e+00 1.00e+00 3.30e-01]
 [     nan 3.00e+00 5.00e+00 1.50e+01 2.00e+00 8.00e+00 8.00e+00 1.35e+02
  0.00e+00 3.00e+00 1.00e+00 1.00e+00]
 [     nan 4.00e+00 1.00e+00 2.60e+02 9.00e+00 7.00e+00 5.00e+00 3.20e+02
  2.50e+01 3.00e+00 1.00e+00 3.30e-01]
 [     nan 4.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.40e+02 1.40e+01 8.00e+00 0.00e+00 3.30e+02
  2.50e+01 3.00e+00 1.00e+00 5.00e-01]
```

Just so you can have an idea of my starting dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Oxj.png)

Python 3.7.1
Numpy 1.15.4
Pandas 0.23.4
Sklearn 0.20.1

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: The dataset which you printed out has `NaN` values in it. You need to decide how to deal with these before you can run PCA. A couple of options might be deleting features with `NaN`s or imputing mean/median values for those `NaN`s.

Comment: I can see the nan values listed under print(x), but cannot understand where in the original dataset this is coming from. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `df.isnull().sum()`. That should tell you which feature(s) have nulls and how many.

Comment: All features returned 0

Comment: Hmm maybe it's only after scaling that the `NaN`s appear. This can happen when all values for one feature are identical I think. Try `np.isnan(x).sum(axis=0)` to see which column they're in.